# bootstrap thumbnail resize - strange behavior of li element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

Hey I pasted clean bootstrap to my theme folder and I have strange problem with thumbnails resize.
`li` resize strange:

[image: http://i49.tinypic.com/muwl83.png]

Look what happen to `li` element - image is resized correctly but `li` is 100% width.

This issue is only on small screens like mobiles. iPad resolution works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

i had  the same problem like you  do on mobile version with default bootstrap and i did a little hack.

```
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
   .thumbnail {
      display: block;
      padding: 4px;
      line-height: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
   }
}
```